# How to improve the UICollectionView's performance? Let it scroll smooth

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm developing an iOS app that use UICollectionView to achieve a module like a normal calendar app. The date cell's background color is changed according to the date (This is not important). The cell is reused with dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier method. However, the calendar is very laggy when srcoll it. I Googled the question and searched it in stackoverflow all day but could not find a perfect answer.

Comment: Does it work slow on an actual device or on simulator? Actually for me it works terrible for some reason on simulator but scroll is really smooth on the device. `UICollectionView` is designed to reuse it cells so just this itself implies good scroll performance.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of things can cause slow scroll performance. You may need to narrow it down and post some code. A couple of common mistakes:

- Re-creating all the subviews when you load data into a cell. You should create subviews once per cell instance, and just clear out their state in `prepareForReuse`
- Removing and re-adding autolayout constraints when reusing cells. If you need to modify autolayout constraints based on the data, it's much, much faster to modify a constant value on an existing constraint than it is to remove and re-add it

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is that your cells are being re-used properly. If not, there's an significant overhead (especially for complex cells) when they're instantiated from a xib.

An easy way to do this is to implement the `-prepareForReuse` method in your cell subclass, and `NSLog` a message. You should see this method fired each time a cell scrolls off screen. If it's not firing, your cells are not being re-used.

Some people have reported a similar problem, possibly a bug in iOS 7. See [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/921033#921033), [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/777551#777551) and [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/846859#846859).

Answer (score 0):

Often it helps to ensure that all the cell are opaque. set shouldRasterize to YES on the layer of the cell (don't forget to set the rasterizationScale).

I also noticed that NSDate operations can be pretty slow. So if you do something with a loop and increasing the nsdate everytime with one day you might also get an increase in performance by just looping from i = 1; i <= numberOfDaysInTheMonth.